# got type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Tags: python, datetime, import

On this line:

```
last_sync_timestamp = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
```

I'm getting the error:

`type object datetime.datetime has no attribute 'datetime'`

I imported `from datetime import datetime`

Comment: Use `datetime.utcnow` instead. With the import you're using, `datetime.datetime.utcnow` would in fact be `datetime.datetime.datetime.utcnow`

Answer (score 0):

The issue stems from the way you've specified the import. Two solutions.

1.

```
import datetime

last_sync_timestamp = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
```

2. 

```
from datetime import datetime
last_sync_timestamp = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow)
```